# How to Display Channel Fields in a Table?

Tags: channel-entries, search, channel

Given a channel with unknown fields (including grids), is there a way to display all the channel's fields in a table? I need a tabular representation of the data I have so that I can sort, filter, etc.

Comment: I'm unclear why the fields would be unknown to you when you are building the templates. Can you explain? Normally you'd just build your templates off of the fields you setup.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't explain well. I was hoping for a pre-made solution. Right now, I am looping through the fields and displaying the entries and then trying to integrate DataTables, etc. I was hoping that EE would already have something like this and I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah EE's not really in the business of pre-made front-end stuff. It's made to be custom templated. You might be able to pull something off with https://github.com/putyourlightson/open-api and some sort of JS plugin.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Can you please put your response as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately EE doesn't really have any built-in facilities for automatically outputting the fields in channels. You'd have to build each template to output whatever fields you wanted.

A potential solution might be to use [Open API](https://github.com/putyourlightson/open-api) which is an API module designed for feeding frontend data. That combined with some JavaScript should be able to get you where you want to go.